# Calling msaccess method of a running access application from c#

Tags: c#

I want to call a msaccess method in my running msaccess application from a c# programm.
In other words, from a c# application I want to call the msaccess method su_MyMethod within my alredy running msaccess application MyAccessApp and pass the parameter strMyParam to that function.

In vb.net it's pretty easy done:

```
Dim objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim objAccess = GetObject("C:\temp\MyAccessApp.accde")
objAccess.Run("su_MyMethod", strMyParam)
objShell.AppActivate("MyAccessApp")
```

How to achieve the same with c# ?
Any help is higly appreciated!
acki

Comment: `CreateObject` and `GetObject` are thin wrappers around `Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgId(...))` and `Marshal.BindToMoniker`. You can actually reference `Microsoft.VisualBasic` and use `using static Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction` to get access to these same methods in C#, though.

Comment: Jeroen, Thx for you quick reply, Let's assume I have the object of the running msaccess app like: `code`Object obj = RunningObjectTable.GetRunningCOMObjectByName(strMyApp);`code` how to invoke now the msaccess method "su_MyMethod" and how to pass the params ?

Comment: There is no `RunningObjectTable` class in the framework, so it would depend entirely on how that's implemented. To a first approximation, you can get late binding to COM by using `dynamic` rather than `object`.

Comment: [link](https://dotnet-snippets.de/snippet/laufende-com-objekte-abfragen/526)

Comment: Jerome, I found a class [see here](https://dotnet-snippets.de/snippet/laufende-com-objekte-abfragen/526) that gives me the com object of my running access application. All I need now is to call the msaccess function ? Just can't figure out how ???

Comment: The following finally worked for me: ````dynamic obj = RunningObjectTable.GetRunningCOMObjectByName(strProc); obj.Run("su_MyMethod", strMyParam); ````